# Is the ViewModel in asp.net comparable to the ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

If you know the MVVM pattern for WPF then you know Josh smith msdn article where a CustomerViewModel does not hold a simple property like:

```
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

Rather a ViewModel wraps a Model and delegates the property access like this:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _customer.FirstName; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _customer.FirstName)
            return;
        _customer.FirstName = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
}
```

I have not seen this in asp.net mvc. Is this due to the missing INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Answer (score 2):

> I have not seen this in asp.net mvc

That's normal. You shouldn't see it. MVC is a different pattern than MVVM. In MVC the view has nobody to notify of any changes. The MVVM pattern is not adapted to the stateless nature of the web.

Comment: good that you said "to the stateless nature of the web" and not "of asp.net" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewModel` and `Model` pieces from MVVM have a different definition than when used in MVC

In MVVM, the `ViewModel` is your application, while the `View` just provides a user-friendly interface for it. In MVC, the `View` is your application, the `ViewModel` provides data for it, and the `Controller` handles application flow and logic.

The Models are also different between the two patterns. In MVC, the `M` represents both data models and view models, while in MVVM the `M` only represents data models.

To summarize, MVC's `M+C` is equal to MVVM's `VM`, and MVC's `M` contains a mix of both MVVM's `M` and `VM` pieces

As a side note, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used by WPF to automatically update the UI when a property changes. This sort of thing is not used in MVC, so not needed.

Comment: Do you have an official MS link where its written that the "M" in the MVC represents (model and viewmodel) ? Never heard of that.

Comment: @Pascal No I don't have an official MS link, it's just my own definition of the patterns. I started with MVVM and more recently have been working with MVC, and the different definitions for `Models` and `ViewModels` really confused me for a while. A `ViewModel` in MVC is a data model meant to contain data for the View, while a `ViewModel` in MVVM is meant to contain things like application logic and command handling in addition to view-specific data.

Comment: The reason why a viewmodel in MVVM has application logic and command handling is because of the technology behind it. MVC and MVVM both patters has viewmodels which validate input logic that is application logic. A ViewModel contains data for the View in asp.net mvc and wpf with mvvm. I do not see any difference there besides the technical ones like binding/commanding etc...