# I am still hesitating to use ViewModels instead of a Model for the View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel

Wether I use Automapper or manually mapping, that plays no role.

All the data for a ReleaseViewModel must be first in the Release because it is filled in the data access layer with it. 90% of my model are like this. Why the overhead of duplicating everything?

What about the KISS principle and over-engineering?

Of course every tool for its appropriate task, but very often I read on SO that not using ViewModels in asp.net mvc is a NO-GO.

Where to draw the line? Should I use ViewModels when they differentiate to 50 %, 75% or 99% from my models ?

I have a model Release:

```
 public class Release
    {      
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int FailedTestsCount { get; set; }
        public int SucceededTestsCount { get; set; }
        public int SumTestsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return SucceededTestsCount + FailedTestsCount;
            }
        }
        public int SumTestingTime { get; set; }
    }
```

a viewmodel ReleaseViewModel:

```
public class ReleaseViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Enter max. 30 chars for a name.")]
    [Remote("ReleaseExists", "Release", ErrorMessage = "This name already exists.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Author { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }    
    public int FailedTestsCount { get; set; }    
    public int SucceededTestsCount { get; set; }    
    public int SumTestsCount 
    {
        get
        {
            return SucceededTestsCount + FailedTestsCount;
        }
    }

    public int SumTestingTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is your release class a DTO or is it a domain object with functionality?

Comment: its a domain object. I do not have many layers to have the need for a dto.

Comment: Why don't you want Name to be required and to be less than 30 char in your domain model?  While your domain model can't show a pretty message to the user, it can still refuse to process if the ModelState.IsValid is false.  At least that's how I think you should do it, but I'm a newbie

Comment: if the required field Name is empty my ModelState is not valid. Everything is fine.

Comment: You are relying on your viewModel validating for your domain model?  Your domain model has no required attributes

Comment: Point being that someone could use your model with a different view somewhere else, and the model wouldn't validate anything, and you can get inconsistent data.

Comment: @Brian sorry for confusing you. My Release model has normally all the validation stuff annotated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ViewModel` is something which is for the **VIEW**. most of the time it is similar to your entity model. But not always.

Look at your example. In your `ViewModel`, you have the `Remote` Attribute and some Validation attributes. So this Remote Name checking is something you add to give a better user experience to your User. It is specific to the View.

Another scenario you need a Viewmodel is for screens where you have more than one models involved. Ex : You have a `User` Entity and a `Project` Entity and you want to provide a screen where a Project can be added to a User. So in this case, you can create a viewmodel to handle that

```
public class ProjectToUserVM
{
  public int UserId { set;get;}
  public string UserName { set;get;}  // i want to display only name of user!
  public int ProjectID { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Projects { set;get}
}
```

Do not use ViewModels for all your Model Entities. Create it when your VIEW really need it.  I use my Model entity objects directly in some views without create a viewmodel sometimes because those are exactly same. Ex : Country / State/ City ( Look up table data.No Add/Edit)

Comment: what means the comment "i want to display only name of user!" ??  And yes remote validation belong to the MVC namespace, but HEY I am doing an mvc application so this coupling is totally OK. Sometimes I have the feeling the SelectListItem class is the top argument of the viewmodel fighters to tell us mortal user we need a viewmodel else the model is bound tightly to mvc, but again its an MVC application. I think 99% of all enterprise apps do not reuse their domain in another application like winforms/wpf thus the web.mvc namespace is fine in the model in my opinion.

Comment: I liked this comment most:"Create it when your VIEW really need it." I will do that and as I do it very seldom I do it manually. Less assembly overhead. Less coupling ;-)

Comment: @Pascal: That comment means, In my ViewModel, i will have properties which are absoluteky needed in my view. Not all the Properties of my Model entity(table columns)

Answer (score 2):

> Why the overhead of duplicating everything?

First of all, you might think *I am duplicating the code*, but the fact is that **you are not**, in case you are doing it, you have a serious design problem

I have found there's one principle that when you do not follow it, it is truly the root of all evil: the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)

Perhaps because you have not found the problem yet, or perhaps, you have and you just have patched your code. **The responsibility of your domain object is totally different to the responsibility to present the data to the user.**

A model in MVC, should be a class representing **all the data the view needs to render and nothing more**. You need to populate this model with data from your domain. (or in a CQRS architecture, from your query services)

If you follow a CQRS architecture (the basics at least, you do not need to implement event sourcing nor use a service bus in order to separate your commands from your queries), this will be clearer to you, the responsibility of a query object is completely different from a command object (an action from your domain)

I think you have misunderstood the KISS principle, while it speaks about over-engineering your code or the YAGNI, that doesn't mean you have to **reuse** everything in your application

Believe me, I learnt this the bad way =(, the only code that should be reused is the infrastructure code, when talking about domain code, it's better to follow always the SRP

Comment: "that doesn't mean you have to reuse everything in your application" DRY.

Comment: You are not breaking the DRY principle... I've been there... you just need to understand the **role** each component is playing. As soon as you understand this, and as soon as you learn to **make roles explicit** you will see the light at the end of the tunnel. Read some articles from Udi Dahan. I've had this discussion many many times and the root is always the same... lack of design theory. And if you insist to follow this approach you will learn (like I did) this the bad way...I think you are falling in the _Silver bullet syndrome..._

Comment: I know why you said this does not break DRY. Because you "replace" DRY with SRP here. YES the ViewMOdel approach ALWAYS is what SRP demands. BUT I prefer to keep it simple, to keep it practical and to keep it to the current requirements. Clean Code says do not engineer it if the chance is not 90% that you need it afair. This is real-life practical you understand? I think you take it too extreme. That you really learnt the bad way you must really have had a big enterprise application.We have a 150K LOC asp.net/wcf  app here but nearly no need for viewmodels.

Comment: Wow, you should be an author. I had an auditory experience reading this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My ViewModels simply wrap a Model, and delegate to it 90% of the time.  They only have behavior of their own when I need to change something about the model's behavior for a specific view use case.  Having the VM there really makes it much easier to add behavior that is only needed for display purposes, especially if that behavior would interfere with your persistence model (e.g. adding properties that you *don't* want persisted).

It's also worth noting that it is quite possible to use an IoC tool like Castle or SpringFramework.net to generate the default forwarding behavior on the fly, reducing the amount of code that you need to write by hand.  This reduces the "duplication cost" fairly dramatically, so it isn't as bad as it seems at first.

Comment: "e.g. adding properties that you don't want persisted)." then do not persist them?! I do not use an ORMapper. "My ViewModels simply wrap a Model, and delegate to it 90% of the time." You do it like in MVVM pattern? That surprises me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213644/is-the-viewmodel-in-asp-net-comparable-to-the-viewmodel-in-wpf

Comment: I guess I do use something like MVVM.  I've always had a bit of a problem with 'pure' MVC, and I find the MVVM paradigm more natural (even for ASP.NET MVC).  YMMV :-)

Answer (score 0):

I second everything Shyju says, especially the part about "when you need it".

If you have a very simple project where your EntityModel classes are in the same library as your ViewModel classes, you may have no need for separate ViewModel dto's and can forgo them. I don't think any *intelligent* person is going to tell you "you did this wrong because you are using entity classes for your view models, dumass." We don't know what the context of your application is. It may be totally appropriate in your case(s).

Some of us define EntityModels in a non-web assembly -- just a plain class library that compiles into a DLL -- for larger projects. When this is the case, we often need to apply special attributes to the view only, such as the RemoteAttribute and HiddenInputAttribute in your example question. However to do this without using a separate viewmodel dto layer means we have to add references to System.Web.Mvc.dll to the EntityModel library, when in fact *that library has nothing else to do with the web*.

Just keep in mind that when you are reusing EntityModel classes in your web projects (i.e. using them as both storage models and presentation models), you are creating a tighter coupling between the web aspects of your project and the business aspects of your project. If you can justify this because of cost/budget, time, target audience, scope, or other constraints, then do it, and ignore your critics because they aren't seeing as big a picture as you are.

Answer (score 0):

if your Release class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and all other stuff you need for your view (validating, commands, ...) then you do not have to use a viewmodel. but if not...

Comment: My Release class is used in an asp.net mvc application. Why should there be INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: oh sorry did not see that there is no WPF tag